# Should I sell a stock that lost value and stays low?

Tags: united-states, stocks, losses

I own a handful (literally 10) shares that have dropped almost 13%. This doesn't amount to a major loss of investment, but a loss nonetheless. The company does not appear to be regaining any value. Rather, it seems to fluctuate between just below what I paid and the 13% or that it sits at now. It's a pharma stock so I've been hopeful that it will remain steady.

I also don't know what the impact on taxes would be.

Does it make sense to just sell it off and take the hit or should I wait to see if it at least gets close to how much I bought it for?

Comment: In which country do you live? How long have you owned the shares?

Comment: Selling investments after they go down in price and buying them after they go up in price is a sure way to lose money. It’s better to do it the other way around.

Comment: @MikeScott Not trying to sell and then rebuy. I'm trying to figure out if it is worth it to hold on to them or cut my losses and buy something else that might actually make me money.

Comment: @HartCO United States

Comment: Holding onto bad investments is another surefire way to lose money Enron? Lehman?  Bear Stearns?

Comment: Are you holding the stock for dividend or growth ? If they're profitable and paying dividends it might not be a bad idea to hold onto it. Also what timeframe are we talking ? what are they working on ? do they have potential ? why did the stock drop ?

Comment: Dividends do not reduce the loss.  Only share price appreciation does.

Comment: @theillien This is a common quandry for investors. Here is the rule I like to apply to resolve it. What you bought it for is sunk cost, ignore that in your decision. The real decision is whether you would BUY that stock at today's price. because when you keep it that is what you are doing. Think of it as a new transaction.

Comment: @xyious Initially I was holding onto it for dividend. But, having lost value, I'm thinking about dumping it and picking up something else that I see as a growth opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing whether it's a good idea to sell the stock now involves knowing what its future price will be.  No one knows that.

Common advice often offered is that you should evaluate the stock to determine what its prospects are going forward and base your hold/sell decision on that.  Well, if people could actually do that, why do they end up with losing stocks?  Others might suggest, would you buy the stock today if you did not own any?  Either way, the reality is that you own the stock at a loss.

Breakevenitis is not a good condition to contract.  If reputable sources such as analysts are downgrading the stock, perhaps you should lose it - though reputable may be debatable in the context of analysts.

Selling the stock will provide a capital loss which you can deduct, subject to the $3,000 limit for individuals (US).  It will reduce you tax liability by your tax bracket rate.

Comment: The $3000 limit is for deducting it from ordinary income, right? My understanding is that there's no limit to how much capital loss you can deduct from capital gains.

Comment: That is correct unless one is a  mark-to-market trader (Trader Tax Status) in which case there is no limit on the amount that one can deduct  capital losses and the wash sale violation is not applicable.